# Call WebApi from another WebAPI in same application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have several webAPIs developed in MVC WebAPI such as

```
public IHttpActionResult SendBroadcast(FinalPayload FinalPayload)
```

And I want to call another web api from inside this API. All my APIs are in the same application. The signature of the second API is

```
public IHttpActionResult SendMessage(Notifications)
```

From the first API i tried

```
this.SendMessage(Notifications)
```

and got error message something like reference to static object ....

I wanted to know if this way of calling webAPI is allowed or do I have to invoke a web client or similar such.

Any help in this will be much appreciated.

Comment: One solution is to extract the logic in the second web api method to a Service/business class and call that instead of trying to create a new request

Comment: I usually put my logic for my API calls into other methods inside of a DLL as shared methods but that's because mine are apart of a asp.net project too.

Comment: did you find my post below useful  user1144596 ??

Answer (score 3):

**1st approach**

You have to redesign the code in your application i.e. Solution.

- Create a class library project. Create an interface for the logic/functions which are common and consumed by different projects.
- Implement the interface in the class library project.
- In different projects(i.e. WebAPI projects) use the interface to access the common functionality.

**2nd Approach**

As thought by you, of-course you can create a web client to access the Web API in another project.

- Its not a good design and your problem is not ACTUALLY solved (just circumvented).
- Poor efficiency, as webclient will use http request to access the code in same solution.
- For future maintenance you may end up creating multiple web clients.

Answer (score 0):

No, as usual you'll need to create a new web client in order to consume the API.

What @Marcus H has suggested in the comment is doable too, just wrap the logic inside *second API* into a separate method (be it instance or static) and invoke it from your *first API* will do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can. You can create a webClient in your controller method method2 that calls method1.

This is a little helper class you could use to help you:

```
namespace Api.Helpers
{
    public static class ApiHelpers
    {
        private static string HttpGet(string url)
        {
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(url);
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
            reader.Close();
            response.Close();
            return responseFromServer;
        }

        public static string HttpPostJson(string url, string json)
        {
            var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
            httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
            httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";

            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream()))
            {
                streamWriter.Write(json);
            }

            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                return result;
            };
        }
    }
}
```

If you want Cookie based authentication, then just use RestSharp instead.
If you use Postman the Chrome extension tool, then if you can access your endpoint, you can automatically generate your C# code.
Simply put the webclient code within the Controller method, and one API call will effectively chain to another.

so in your ApiController you'd write something like:

```
IHttpActionResult method1() {
    var result = ApiHelpers.HttpGet("http://thing.com/test");
    return Ok(result);
}
```